# Lost debug.keystore file

Tags: android, sqlite, android-keystore

I distributed an .apk (debug mode) file to a closed user group (through email). They played around with the application and some data is stored in the sqlite database (internal storage). Recently, my machine crashed and lost everything including debug.keystore. I need to give an updated build now (from new machine) but as you know, it wont install on top of the old build because of key mismatch.

That data stored in sqlite database is very important so is there any way I can get that db file? Also, If I root the phone will I be able to install an update on top of already installed build without key mismatch or can I at least get that db file so that I can access the data using another application?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should put effort on finding keystore. Because As I know there is no solution.

Comment: System formatted. There is no way I can get that old debug.keystore back. I also tried to get debug.keystore file from old .apk file but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your error was that you distribute your apk signed by debug.keystore. That is wrong and you face a consequence of this action. debug.keystore is generated dynamicly and can change often (for example reinstal of android studio) and you don't have assurance that next build will be signed with same key. From that point you are not able to update your app even Google itself can't help.

As far as i know the only chance for you is to get the db file manualy from the phone install new version of your app with new release.keystore and swap the new empty db file with old one.

Note that if your db file is in private storage of your app you need root to access that file.

if you already have access to file here is adb command for pulling file to PC:

```
adb pull /sdcard/absolute/path/to/file/database.db C:/destination/of/file/on/PC
```